# organisations splitting departments into smaller groups that work from different offices, or through alternating work from home (WFH) schedules

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Right now we see organisations splitting departments into smaller groups that work from different offices, **or through alternating work from home (WFH) schedules** in a bid to do their part in the COVID-19 battle.

Does the sentence mean "groups either work from different offices or work through WFH", but that doesn't sound right to me?

I would think it as departments either splitted into groups or departments work through WFH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your reading:

"Organisations are splitting departments" either:
1 into smaller groups that work from different offices
or
2 through alternating WFH schedules.

It's a poor structure, because 1 describes a manner of splitting departments, while 2 describes a means of splitting departments, yet they are combined under the word "or" as if they were the same sort of thing.

A better expression might be
"Organizations are splitting departments into smaller groups that work in separate offices, or that work from home with alternating schedules."